# AngularJS dynamic/wildcard routes

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I'm completely new to Angular, and am trying to sort out some dynamic/wildcard routes so I don't have to define each page manually.

I've got a module like so:

```
function() {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("app", ["ngRoute", "ngAnimate", "ui.bootstrap", "easypiechart", "ui.tree", "ngMap", "ngTagsInput", "angular-loading-bar", "app.controllers", "app.directives", "app.localization", "app.nav", "app.ui.ctrls", "app.ui.directives", "app.ui.services", "app.ui.map", "app.form.validation", "app.ui.form.ctrls", "app.ui.form.directives", "app.tables", "app.task", "app.chart.ctrls", "app.chart.directives", "app.page.ctrls"]).config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
        var routes, setRoutes;
        return routes = ["dashboard", "pages/404", "actions/ActionOne", "actions/ActionTwo"], setRoutes = function(route) {
        //                                                    ^      and      ^
            var config, url;
            return url = "/" + route, config = {
                templateUrl: "views/" + route + ".html"
            }, $routeProvider.when(url, config), $routeProvider
        }, routes.forEach(function(route) {
            return setRoutes(route)
        }), $routeProvider.when("/", {
            redirectTo: "/dashboard"
        }).when("/404", {
            templateUrl: "views/pages/404.html"
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/404"
        })
    }])
```

`ActionOne` and `ActionTwo` are examples of some action pages, but there could be a couple dozen or so, and they change sometimes.

How can I set this up to support a wildcard (e.g., `actions/:action`) so I can use that parameter to dynamically determine the route?

---

Comment: Not sure what you are asking because the wild card you are showing is valid as it is and is outlined in the `ngRoute` docs

Comment: @charlietfl trying to figure out how to use it isn't clear at all in the docs. Hence me asking the question here.

Comment: Did a quick google search and found this [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/MxJkCpJDKXDNyYc1web8?p=preview) from this [tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-routing-and-views-tutorial-with-example/)

Comment: @charlietfl I suspect you missed the part where I indicated I'm new to Angular. That tutorial isn't helpful in doing what I need to do with the existing code I've provided.

Comment: Need to narrow down where problem lies a bit more then. Demo was intended to show how wildcard works, and how to get the route param in controller produced by wildcard

Comment: @charlietfl updated with my attempt at integrating that tutorial.

Comment: shouldn't be `return routes` looks like a whole bunch of syntax errors also in original block of code

Comment: @charlietfl nevermind, I figured it out. Thanks for your time anyway ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized I can't add it into the array of routes defined here; used the designated `when()` syntax, and all is well:

```
function() {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("app", ["ngRoute", "ngAnimate", "ui.bootstrap", "easypiechart", "ui.tree", "ngMap", "ngTagsInput", "angular-loading-bar", "app.controllers", "app.directives", "app.localization", "app.nav", "app.ui.ctrls", "app.ui.directives", "app.ui.services", "app.ui.map", "app.form.validation", "app.ui.form.ctrls", "app.ui.form.directives", "app.tables", "app.task", "app.chart.ctrls", "app.chart.directives", "app.page.ctrls"]).config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
        var routes, setRoutes;
        return routes = ["dashboard", "pages/404", "pages/500"], setRoutes = function(route) {
            var config, url;
            return url = "/" + route, config = {
                templateUrl: "views/" + route + ".html"
            }, $routeProvider.when(url, config), $routeProvider
        }, routes.forEach(function(route) {
            return setRoutes(route)
        }), $routeProvider.when("/", {
            redirectTo: "/dashboard"
        }).when("/actions/:name", {
            templateUrl: "views/pages/action.html"
        }).when("/controls/:name", {
            templateUrl: "views/pages/control.html"
        }).when("/404", {
            templateUrl: "views/pages/404.html"
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/404"
        })
    }])
```